# Can Flutter apps share Firestore cache?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a series of apps for my business using Flutter and a shared Firestore database backend.  These apps retrieve data and use the automatic Firestore caching to pull it back up later without having to call the server again.

Can I have multiple apps share the same cache?  For example, if one app has fetched all documents in the employees collection, and another needs a single employee, can it pull it from the other app's cache?  Or a shared one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firestore SDK was not designed to share cache among apps.  I'm not going to say that it's not possible, but you'd have to go through **a lot of trouble** in your own code to make this happen.  The reason is because modern mobile operating systems isolate each app to its own space for reading and writing (aka "sandboxing").  This is a security feature meant to provide security to the end user so that malicious apps can't simply access other app data.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks!